# awk等で、あるフィールド以降のすべてのフィールドを表示させたい

Tags: awk, grep

あるDIRに複数の「空白を含むファイル名（PDF名など）」が存在し、日付やWORDを含むファイル名で検索し、のちに結果を表示したいときがあります。

```
ls -la
-rw-rw-rw-  1 admin administrator  11794593  9月  3  2014 Cambridge University Press Programming in Mathematica An Introduction 2013 .pdf
```

このとき、空白がないなら `ls -la` などの後ファイル名のフィールド番号を指定すれば良いのはわかります。

```
ls -la | awk '/pdf/{print $9}'
Cambridge
```

しかし、空白がいくつかありますと、希望通りの結果が得られず難儀しております。
アドバイスよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 例えばファイル名だけ表示したい場合には `ls -1a` とする事もできますが、この方法で解決しますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
LANG=C ls -laN $1 | awk '{
    re="^([^ ]+ +){7}[^ ]+ "
    match($0, re)
    num = RLENGTH + 1
    print substr($0, num)
}'
```

awkのスクリプトの中で、lsの結果であるファイルを切り出したいとき、ファイル名に空白が含まれるとやっかいですね。
awkのデフォルトのデリミタは空白ですが、連続するデリミタは1個と解釈されるため、いったんフィールドに分解してしまうと空白の数を復元できません。

lsの結果を使いたいとき、ファイル名までのフィールドを削除するしか解決の方法を思いつきませんでした。
こちらの環境では、51文字目からファイル名でしたので$0から先頭の50文字を削除しています。
Nオプションを付けずにlsを実行すると、空白を含むファイルの前後に引用符が付加されますので、Nオプションで抑止しています。

確認に使用したlsのバージョンです。
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.28

---

追記
状況によって「ファイル名の開始位置が変わる」とのご指摘をいただきましたのでコードを修正しました。
空白で始まるファイル名にも対応しました。

Comment: 「env LANG=C ls -laN」とすると言語設定に依存しなくなるので桁数の決め打ちがしやすくなります。

ただし、
> -rw-rw-r--  1 (ユーザ名) (グループ名)    0  6月 22 11:21  aaa
のように、「ls -l」の出力のユーザ名とグループ名の桁数が一定ではないので、汎用化を考える点でやっかいです。

Comment: hidezzzさん、ご指摘ありがとうございました。全然考えていませんでした。回答を修正しましたので、よろしければご確認ください。

Comment: ファイル名の先頭に空白がある場合、それを取り出すことが出来ないです(今回の質問ではそういうケースはなさそうな気がしますが…)。「ls -l」の出力中のファイル名の左側に空白は必ず1文字の区切り文字があり、それ以上の空白文字があったらファイル名の先頭の空白として処理する必要があります。

Comment: hidezzzさん、重ね重ねありがとうございます。全然気づきませんでした。

Comment: おつかれさまです。指摘点が修正されたことを確認しました。

Answer (score 0):

@cubick さんコメントのように、コマンドの引数で表示させる情報を指定できるなら、それを使えば良いと思われます。

それが出来ない情報やコマンドからも取得したいとか、既に取得済みで全ての情報を含んでテキスト化したファイルから抽出したいといった場合は、`index`や`match`と`substr`が使えるのではないでしょうか？

[awkのmatch()関数の使い方](https://it-ojisan.tokyo/awk-match/)
[match()関数とsubstr()関数で文字列を切り出す](https://it-ojisan.tokyo/awk-match/#keni_toc_4)

[awkでsubstr()の切り出し開始位置をindex()で指定する方法](https://it-ojisan.tokyo/awk-index-substr/)

[awkでsubstr()を使って文字列を切り出す方法](https://it-ojisan.tokyo/awk-substr/)

ファイル名,フォルダ名ならこんな感じで:
(フィールドが9個無い場合、別の物が表示されたので最小桁位置でチェックしています)

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -la | awk '
{
  match($0, $9)
  if (RSTART >= 17) {
    datatext = substr($0, RSTART)
    print datatext
  }
}
'
```

ファイルの日付フィールドから切り出したい場合は数字をずらすだけで:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -la | awk '
{
  match($0, $6)
  if (RSTART >= 11) {
    datatext = substr($0, RSTART)
    print datatext
  }
}
'
```

`match`ではなく`index`を使う場合はこちら:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls -la | awk '
{
  column = index($0, $6)
  if (column >= 11) {
    datatext = substr($0, column)
    print datatext
  }
}
'
```

Comment: みなさん、いろいろご教授ありがとうございます。
たとえば、ls -la の場合、ファイル名は$9と自明ですから、awk等で$0-$8以外というような指定は困難なのでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 検索するとn番目以降を`for`で回す例が良く出てくるようです。[awkでn列目以降を出力](https://it-ojisan.tokyo/awk-from-nth-column/) しかし途中の空白文字の長さが一定でない場合は情報として正しく組み立てられないでしょう。指定したいフィールドの先頭に空白が含まれないという条件ならどの回答も動くでしょうし、先頭に空白の可能性があるなら私のではなく@hidezzzさん, @akira ejiriさんの回答を使う/応用することになるでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

cubick さんが指摘されているように「ls -1a」(またはls -1A」)でやるのが良いと思います。

「ls -lA」の出力から空白を再現したファイル名を切り出すのは意外と面倒です。
以下一応やってみました。
split()関数でカラムとセパレータを分割して切り出してから、必要部分を出力する感じになります。
見やすさのために出力の行頭と行末に「|」を入れるようにしています。

```
$ touch "   000" "aaa" "bbb bbb" "ccc ccc   ccc" "ddd ddd    ddd   "
$ ls -lA
合計 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 0  6月 22 11:21 '   000'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 0  6月 22 11:21  aaa
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 0  6月 22 11:21 'bbb bbb'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 0  6月 22 11:21 'ccc ccc   ccc'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hidezzz hidezzz 0  6月 22 11:21 'ddd ddd    ddd   '
$ls -lA | awk 'NR>1{split($0,a," ",sep);printf "|" substr(sep[8],2) ;for(i=9;i<=length(a);++i){printf a[i] sep[i]}print "|"}'
|   000|
|aaa|
|bbb bbb|
|ccc ccc   ccc|
|ddd ddd    ddd   |
```